# How can I make a webhook for the project with CI job?

Tags: curl, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to make a webhook from a CI job using API. I have dozens of projects to use it for so I don't want to use private user token for it.
I tried this:
`curl --location --request POST  -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}" 'https://gitlabcom.com/api/v4/projects/100/hooks?id=100&url=https://blabla.com/hooks/$TOKEN&job_events=true&push_events=false&token=$TOKEN'`
But it returns 401 error.
Any ideas I can make a webhook for the project with CI job?
Or is there a token that suits a group of projects and can be used to POST with API?

Answer (score 0):

I confused "project" token (that doesn't suit my needs) and "personal" token that can be created from user's profile. Personal token can do what I need with API.